# How to resolve Kernel Error or Memory Error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, dask-distributed

I had and array of strings whose length is 50000. I am trying to create a a similarity matrix of dimension 50000 * 500000. In order to make it i tried forming the list of tuples using the following code:

```
terms = [element for element in itertools.product(array1,array1)]
```

But I am getting memory error or kernel error. It was not able to move forward.

I have also followed this question in stack overflow: 
[Spark Unique pair in cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027848/spark-unique-pair-in-cartesian-product)
This is very similar to my implementation of calculating the distances(due to symmetry i can make use of upper or lower triangle in a matrix). Is there any way of getting it done by means of spark or any other ways of working with partitions or in other means. Any idea would be appreciated.

**Toy example for small array:**

```
array1 = np.array(['hello', 'world', 'thankyou'])
terms = [element for element in itertools.product(array1,array1)]
```

Output of terms:

```
[('hello', 'hello'),
 ('hello', 'world'),
 ('hello', 'thankyou'),
 ('world', 'hello'),
 ('world', 'world'),
 ('world', 'thankyou'),
 ('thankyou', 'hello'),
 ('thankyou', 'world'),
 ('thankyou', 'thankyou')]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the matrix? Maybe the generator is enough?

Answer (score 2):

50000 * 50000 is 2GB+ elements in the list. Each list element takes 4 bytes (+36 byte overhead for the list). Multiply that with the average string length (6 in your example) + 21 (number of bytes overhead per string). Which means that you'll need to have 216+ GB of RAM just for this single statement (this is on top of memory for your OS, other programs, etc).  I think you're hitting real world limitations and need to find better algorithms.